# JDBC connection open or closed?

Tags: java

I have a Java application with a JDBC connection, which performs many different tasks. My question is what is best for performance:

- To have an open connection for the duration of the application running?
- Close and reopen connection based on what tasks are performed and create new connection variables?

Answer (score 4):

Connection reuse is the best approach, since opening a new connection each time is not a light operation.
That is why there are [connection pools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool). You have a set of connections cached and managed by the pool. Each time you get a connection and return it back.

Answer (score 0):

you should consider re-using connections rather than creating a new one each time

I have recommend the Semaphore class to manage the [connections](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_concurrency_semaphore2.shtml);